# Add selected class on scroll at last item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Add selected class on page scroll(not on click) at last item, other item selections are working. For more see [image]

**My Script to add selected class on page scroll.**

```
//Selected Using Scroll
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
        $('#side-nav-id .scrollTo').each(function () {
            var currentLink = $(this);
            var refElement = $(currentLink.attr("href"));
            if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPosition + 100) {
                $('#side-nav-id .scrollTo').removeClass("selected");
                currentLink.addClass("selected");
            }
            else{
                currentLink.removeClass("selected");
            }
        });
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the last section title is never reaching the position limit you've established with...

```
if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPosition + 100) {
```

... because of the content length (is not enough to allow the title to reach that point)

I supposed this is a common problem with this behaviour, because if you have short sections, the last ones will never reach the top.

Some options you could use...

1. Put the limit down, so your last section reach it. Not very cool, because if the last section is very short, you'd have to put the limit superlow, so the whole behaviour breaks.
2. Add padding at the end of the container to allow the scroll continue until the last section reach that limit.
3. Add some 'else' to check if your're at the bottom of the page and in that case highlight the last menu item. Something like...

   ```
   else if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
   ```

I hope it helps

Comment: Can we find top level section visible on window ?. Then we will apply selected class on top level section visible on window on scroll. For more you can see above image only one section is visible with its starting point.

Comment: To do that you'll need to query the whole document, get the elements offset positions, and match that agains the scrollTop value of the window. But anyway, I think is not a good solution. Once a section appears at the bottom of the page, your meny highlight change, even though teh whole page is about the previous section. And what happens if you have more than one section in a window? Show the last

Comment: Honestly, for this situation the option that makes more sense to me is adding the padding at the bottom. Everything will work as expected independently of the length of the sections.